# Can you get the AWS account name from boto?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto

I have an AWS key and secret key and would like to call `boto` to get the account name.

I can get account ID, but the AWS account name is a mystery.

Comment: Please check answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709461/get-aws-account-id-from-boto

Comment: It appears that this question specifically refers to boto2 as boto3 wasn't out when this question was asked. Just for fun I checked and the initial commit was actually 6 hours after this question was posted: https://github.com/boto/boto3/commit/a33e1f8595e8d4cf70b8d5c0b1a7657124adc6a2 :)

Answer (score 28):

To get the AWS account alias in `boto3`:

```
alias = boto3.client('iam').list_account_aliases()['AccountAliases'][0]
```

- While the API response allows for multiple account aliases, [AWS docs on aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html#CreateAccountAlias) say there can be only one per account.
- The [account alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html#AboutAccountAlias) is not the same as the [account name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SetUp/latest/UserGuide/setup-acctrequirements.html), but it's alphanumeric and more usable than account number.  The alias must be created under IAM settings for account (or [using AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-account-alias.html)) - not all accounts will have an alias.
- Getting the alias doesn't require as much privilege to access as getting the account name [via the boto3 `organizations` service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43499529/992887).

To get account ID (account number):

```
id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
```

Answer (score 7):

from [Get AWS Account ID from Boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709461/get-aws-account-id-from-boto#answer-39125640)

```
id = boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity().get('Account')
```

then

```
name =   boto3.client('organizations').describe_account(AccountId=id).get('Account').get('Name')
```

Comment: getting name resulted in botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError

Comment: This is only useful if account is member of any organization.

Answer (score 3):

Its late but might be helpful for future.
If you are using organization service then using below code you can fetch **Account Name**.

```
org = boto3.client('organizations')
account_name = org.describe_account(AccountId='account-id').get('Account')
print(account_name ['Name'])
```

[For more info](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/organizations.html#Organizations.Client.describe_account)

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible if you're using IAM and you want to retrieve that alias. If you have root credentials, it's not possible to retrieve the account name.

The related call is: `get_account_alias()`

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/iam.html#boto.iam.connection.IAMConnection.get_account_alias

Comment: The alias is not the same as the account name.