# Get AWS Account ID from Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have an AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and an AWS_SECRET_KEY.  These are active credentials, so they belong to an active user, who belongs to an AWS Account.  How, using Boto3, do I find the ID of this AWS Account?

Comment: Some methods mentioned here https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/6d4974b7503336d642c9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the current user account-id in boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33332050/getting-the-current-user-account-id-in-boto3)

Comment: @MarnixKlooster This question comes up first on Google for the search "Boto Account ID".  Maybe mark the other question as the duplicate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thanks to [@louahola](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39125640/2800876) for the improvement on my initial answer.

This will get you the Account ID for your key pair:

```
import boto3

sts = boto3.client(
    "sts", aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
account_id = sts.get_caller_identity()["Account"]
```

If you are running on an EC2 instance with [IAM role-based permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) or any of [boto3's other credential options](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html), you can do this even easier:

```
import boto3

account_id = boto3.client("sts").get_caller_identity()["Account"]
```

Comment: You can also set a default for each parameter to None, in which case it retrieves the account number for the current profile, assuming you have that setup. In that way, one can avoid passing around keys and use assumed roles, such as when running on an EC2 instance or via the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 72):

The AccountID can be grabbed from the get-caller-identity sts function. This returns an "Account" field:

```
client = boto3.client("sts", aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
account_id = client.get_caller_identity()["Account"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this will work:

```
import boto3

ACCESS_KEY = 'FOO'
SECRET_KEY = 'BAR'

iam = boto3.resource('iam',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
)
account_id = iam.CurrentUser().arn.split(':')[4]

print account_id
```

If you use EC2 IAM roles, you can omit all of the access/secret key stuff and the code becomes simply:

```
iam = boto3.resource('iam')
account_id = iam.CurrentUser().arn.split(':')[4]
```