# Get Account ID from Account Alias (boto3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Provided with an AWS Account alias, I would like to convert it to an AWS Account ID. I don't think there is an API for this, as the IAM alias commands in boto3 are limited to [create, delete and list](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/iam-example-managing-account-aliases.html), but I figured I would at least ask the community.

My use case is to allow a user to provide either an account alias or account ID to the [sts.assume_role()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) call. If an account ID is specified, great, we can simply build a role_arn from that and pass it to the function call. If an account alias is provided, we need to first convert it to an account ID, then build the role_arn in the same fashion.

Comment: I think it's impossible unless user provide you some credentials. Then you can refer to [Get AWS Account ID from Boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709461/get-aws-account-id-from-boto) to do this.

Comment: yeah I think so too... I guess account id's are sensitive and this is a security constraint.