# How to confirm which AWS account I am launching Sceptre on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sceptre

I use Sceptre to manage AWS infrastructure, but not always in a CI/CD pipeline. Sometimes updates are manual. In that case, the engineer will set the environment variables corresponding to the AWS account (usually there are three accounts per project, dev-pre-pro), and in the project folder execute something like `sceptre launch pre`.

There appears a problem when the AWS account in the environment is not actually the right account, for example executing `sceptre launch pre` when the environment keys are for the `dev` project. While of course people shouldn't mess up, and usually any mistakes are caught by warnings, I would like to prevent errors, and I think the best way would be to explicitly set an account number in the configuration and have sceptre check in some pre-hook that it is actually accessing that account before attempting any modification.

How would that best be done? I know how to [identify the account number using plain boto commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709461/get-aws-account-id-from-boto); can I simply put some plain python pre-hook that would get the account keys from the environment, the expected account number from a sceptre parameter, and abort on any discrepancy, or is there a better way?

Comment: use STS `get_caller_identity`

Comment: @MattTimmermans I know how to do that, but I'm not sure how to run it from inside sceptre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is provision for hooks with `sceptre` templates as well. See: [hook-docs](https://docs.sceptre-project.org/latest/docs/hooks.html#hooks)

You can either run `aws-cli` command with hook like below:

```
template:
  path: vpc-sample.yaml
  type: file
parameters:
  CidrBlock: ...
hooks:
  before_launch:
    - !cmd "aws configure get region"
    - !cmd ...
```

Or if you want to do a bit more, you can try creating a custom hook. Ref: [custom-hooks](https://docs.sceptre-project.org/latest/docs/hooks.html#custom-hook-py)

Comment: I actually knew about hooks but didn't realize I could trigger one "before_launch". Looks like this will solve the problem indeed.

Comment: Glad I am able to help @Law29